# Calculation in Pandas Dataframe for a selected row by using the values of row above and below

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas Dataframe and would like to perform calculations in rows, which are surrounded by rows with the string value "NIST" in the sample column.

```
date116/120 117/120 118/120 119/120 122/120 124/120 sample                          
2015-05-03 15:22:00 0.446305    0.235479    0.743318    0.263526    0.142027    0.177417    NIST 100ppb
2015-05-03 15:31:00 0.446106    0.235352    0.743078    0.263473    0.142046    0.177475    SPEX 100ppb
2015-05-03 15:40:00 0.446238    0.235403    0.743182    0.263491    0.142041    0.177445    NIST 100ppb
2015-05-03 15:48:00 0.446111    0.235356    0.743072    0.263472    0.142048    0.177499    SPEX 100ppb
2015-05-03 15:57:00 0.446259    0.235415    0.743217    0.263511    0.142051    0.177446    NIST 100ppb
```

The calculation should look like that:

```
df = ((df / (df.shift(1) + df.shift(-1)))-1)*1000
```

Comment: What's the question exactly?  Your code is fine, but you need to limit it to numeric columns.  E.g. `df.iloc[:,:-2]` or `df[ df.columns[ df.dtypes != 'object' ] ]`

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: I would like to perform the calculation in the whole data frame for only the rows which have a row above and below with the sample "NIST 100ppb". What is the easiest way to select them and calculate the values? In the end I need a new data frame, containing the columns "date", "116/120", ..., "124/120", "sample", with only the calculated rows. Thanks for your help.